# How to resize to fit without antialiasing with rmagick

Tags: ruby, resize, imagemagick, rmagick

**What I'm not looking for**

I'm currently not searching how to resize to fit without antialiasing with ImageMagick. I know this answer can be found quickly on the web as quite every questions have been already asked on ImageMagick.

**Context**

The context is I get a big image that I have to resize to fit multiple kind of screens. In almost all cases, everything goes fine, but for little dimensions, I've got some blur issues due to aliasing.
My images are all black & white and very simple (it's barcodes), so I don't need any aliasing.

**What I'm looking for**

What I'm looking for is how to resize properly with RMagick, the ruby implementation of ImageMagick.
For the moment, I'm using the `resize_to_fit` method to resize an image but I've got an issue with aliasing and there is no options to pass to the method which could disable it.

I'm currently considering writing a method that does the same as `resize_to_fit` but with the ability to disable aliasing but no decision taken for the moment.

Comment: Could [Magick::Image.sample](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#sample) be what your looking for? You'll need to calculate `resize_to_fit` yourself, but that's a one-liner.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get better results using a special-purpose resampling [filter](https://rmagick.github.io/constants.html#FilterTypes) for the smaller sizes. Different filters have different strengths and weaknesses depending on the kind of image you're resizing. Try using the [resize](https://rmagick.github.io/image3.html#resize) method instead of resize_to_fit. The resize method lets you specify which filter to use. [Here's information](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/) about ImageMagick's filters. You may have to do some trial-and-error evaluation to see which filter works best with your images.

Also remember that JPEG images naturally introduce compression artifacts, so you might try saving these images as GIFs or PNGs or even TIFFs, if you're not already doing so.

Need some help with computing the new size of the image? You can couple resize with [change_geometry](https://rmagick.github.io/image1.html#change_geometry) to get the behavior of resize_to_fit.